# Driver for Beaglebone Motor Cape

Tags: gpio, beagleboneblack, pwm

Are there any existing driver libraries (C/C++ preferred) for the Beaglebone [Motor Cape](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/GHI-Electronics/MRTCPE-BBBCAPE?qs=lYGu3FyN48fyjZuUoploBg%3D%3D)?  If not, what would be the best examples/tutorials to follow for starting to interact directly with this cape?

I have previously used the [Robot Control Library](http://strawsondesign.com/docs/librobotcontrol/) for interacting with the H-bridge motor drivers on the [Robotics Cape](http://www.strawsondesign.com/#!board-default), but the pinout is different between the two capes.  I don't know how easy or hard it would be to adapt the Robot Control Library to the Motor Cape versus writing something specifically for the Motor Cape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a book for beaglebone black and motors by Prabakar. It is called, "BeagleBone by Example."

He goes into motors for bots a bit. Also...

https://github.com/silver2row/motocape is something I set up a while back when I first got the MotorCape from GHI.

It is a start.

It is in Python3 and not C/C++ but I am sure you can port it to C/C++ easily enough.

Comment: This was what I need to get started.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some initial testing in python based upon @de-funct answer above, I ended up adapting the Robot Control Library to work with the Motor Cape.

See [Compile the Robot Control Library for a different beaglebone cape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66340344/compile-the-robot-control-library-for-a-different-beaglebone-cape/66394399#66394399) for that saga.